# How to remove last appended innerhtml and update total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get my remove links to remove the last appended html fields and update the total being calculated.  I'd also like for the calculations to happen onblur rather than on click as currently I have to add a blank last product to get the total to update.

JQuery

```
<script>
var counter = 1;
function addNumber(divName){    
  var sum = document.getElementById('product_cost');
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'product_' + counter + '';
  newdiv.className = 'additional_product';
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='product_fields_inner'><select id='courses' class='course_name_dropdown'><option value='Course1'>Course 1</option></select><select id='delivery' class='delivery_mode_dropdown'><option value='Face to face'>Face to Face</option></select><input type='text' class='course_cost_text_field' name='number" + counter + "'><input class='course_cost_text_field' type='text'><input class='course_cost_text_field' type='date'></div><a href='#' class='remove' id='remove'>-</a>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  sum.value = getSum(counter);
  counter++;    
}

function getSum(numberOfDivs){
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i=0 ; i<numberOfDivs; i++) {
     sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByName('number' + i)[0].value);
    }
   return sum;
}

$("html").on('click', 'a#remove', function(){
   $('#total #product_' + counter + '').last().remove();
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="total" class="product_fields">
  <div id="product_0">
    <div class="product_fields_inner">
      <select class="course_name_dropdown" name="product_description[]" value="">
        <option id="Course1" value="Course1">Course 1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="delivery_mode_dropdown" name="delivery_mode[]">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" id="course_cost_1" 
name="number0">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" name="location[]">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="date" name="start_date[]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you target you element like this :

```
$('#total div[id^="product_"]:last-child').remove();
```

```js
var counter = 1;
function addNumber(divName){    
  var sum = document.getElementById('product_cost');
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.id = 'product_' + counter + '';
  newdiv.className = 'additional_product';
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='product_fields_inner'><select id='courses' class='course_name_dropdown'><option value='Course1'>Course 1</option></select><select id='delivery' class='delivery_mode_dropdown'><option value='Face to face'>Face to Face</option></select><input type='text' class='course_cost_text_field' name='number" + counter + "'><input class='course_cost_text_field' type='text'><input class='course_cost_text_field' type='date'></div><a href='#' class='remove' id='remove'>-</a>";
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  sum.value = getSum(counter);
  counter++;    
}

function getSum(numberOfDivs){
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i=0 ; i<numberOfDivs; i++) {
     sum += parseInt(document.getElementsByName('number' + i)[0].value);
    }
   return sum;
}

$("html").on('click', 'a#remove', function(){
   $('#total div[id^="product_"]:last-child').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total" class="product_fields"><a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
  <div id="product_0">
    <div class="product_fields_inner">
      <select class="course_name_dropdown" name="product_description[]" value="">
        <option id="Course1" value="Course1">Course 1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="delivery_mode_dropdown" name="delivery_mode[]">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" id="course_cost_1" 
name="number0">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" name="location[]">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="date" name="start_date[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="product_1">
    <div class="product_fields_inner">
      <select class="course_name_dropdown" name="product_description[]" value="">
        <option id="Course1" value="Course1">Course 1</option>
      </select>
      <select class="delivery_mode_dropdown" name="delivery_mode[]">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" id="course_cost_1" 
name="number0">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="text" name="location[]">
      <input class="course_cost_text_field" type="date" name="start_date[]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work however removes all of my appended products not just the last one.

Comment: @Park Productions Sorry your post got only one node (html) so i update the html in my example to show you how will be the nodes. i don't remove all. I guess you did something wrong. i suggest post all of the html to be sure you are targetting helpers in the good way. Regards.